# How to randomly select a file with batch-file?

Tags: batch-file, audio, ffmpeg, merge, mp3

I'm new with ffmpeg, and I tried to find the Answers but didn't help.

I have 4 Audio file name : audio1.mp3 , audio2.mp3 , audio3.mp3 , audio4.mp3
and i want to merg those mp3 to those mp4 one by one with loop.
Here my code bath file that's i tried.

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i ("*.mp3") -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -shortest "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\MyOutputVideo\%%~na.mp4" pause
```

Here what I expect to be like this :

```
|-----------VIDEO1-----------|
|-----------AUDIO1.mp3-----|
|-----------VIDEO2-----------|
|-----------AUDIO2.mp3-----|
|-----------VIDEO3-----------|
|-----------AUDIO3.mp3-----|
|-----------VIDEO4-----------|
|-----------AUDIO4.mp3-----|
|-----------VIDEO5-----------|
|-----------AUDIO1.mp3-----|
|-----------VIDEO6-----------|
|-----------AUDIO2.mp3-----|
```

Comment: Do you require the order of the MP3 files to be random?

Comment: yes, absolutely I want the MP3 file to be random .
Can you tell me more if I want the MP3 to be order what code I should put. Thanks

Comment: ffmpeg has no feature to randomize inputs. That is a job for [tag:batch-file] scripting. I suggest adding the [tag:batch-file] tag, and edit the question title to something like: *How to randomly select a file with batch-file?*

Comment: If so , if I want the MP3 to be order what code I should put. Thanks

Comment: Again, that is a batch-file question, not a ffmpeg specific question. But I am not a Windows user so I can't help with batch-file. Maybe someone else can now that you edited the title and added the tag.

Comment: No one can help ?

Comment: 1) I'm guessing regular batch-file answerers are assuming you need help with ffmpeg too, so there may be few users who know both topics. 2) Your question title and comments mention randomization, but the content of your question does not, so it may be unclear what you really want to do.